# How to setcontentView with subfolder

Tags: java, android, xml, directory, contentview

i have this layout inside a folder menu< xxx.xml

How suppose i call it in java? setContentView(R.layout.xxx.xml);(i got error)

i already trying add the path to the gradle but without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong the folder. You need to move the xxx.xml to the `layout` folder

As the following:

```
R.layout.xmlfile -> res/layout/xmlfile.xml
R.menu.xmlfile  -> res/menu/xmlfile.xml
```

Comment: yes, but if i don't want to move xml file to the layout folder?